# Setting file path for Windows in IPython

Tags: python, windows, path, ipython

I am trying to set a path in Python to a folder, but I can't seem to get `(PATH)` to work. It works when I write out the path. Any ideas?

```
PATH = "data/dogscats"
sz = 224 
print(PATH)
#!dir /b "data/dogscats" <---- THIS WORKS
!dir /b (PATH)  <------ THIS DOESN'T
```

---

data/dogscats

FILE NOT FOUND

Comment: Ba Bam  That was it Thanks

Comment: What was it? If your question is solved, it would be awesome if you could document that here, so that others can learn from it as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @jotaen, I speculated about a possible answer in a comment. After Joe confirmed that it worked, I edited the question title and tags to to add IPython and moved my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`!dir /b "$PATH"` should do what you want, or use an expression such as `!dir /b {'"%s"' % PATH}`. See the [IPython reference](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/reference.html#manual-capture-of-command-output-and-magic-output) for more information. Note that because the path uses forward slash as a separator, it has to be quoted in Windows CMD in order to disambiguate the separator from a "/" option.